# How do I filter my DB query results to not display any duplicate value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query like this:

```
$blog = BlogModel::select('user_id')->get();
```

and it return this

```
[{"user_id":2},{"user_id":3},{"user_id":4},{"user_id":4},{"user_id":6}]
```

I would like Delete duplicate user_id like this

```
[{"user_id":2},{"user_id":3},{"user_id":4},{"user_id":6}]
```

Comment: hint: use distinct

Answer (score 2):

You can use DISTINCT for that purpose

```
$blog = BlogModel::select('user_id')->distinct()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinct() to force the query to return distinct results.

Try change this:

```
$blog = BlogModel::select('user_id')->get();
```

To:

```
$blog = BlogModel::select('user_id')->distinct()->get();
```

You can read more here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries

Answer (score 0):

```
$blog = BlogModel::selectRaw('distinct user_id')->get();
```